# Angularjs filter callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, angularjs

I have a list of items that are being filtered with an Angularjs filter. Here is Jade markup:

```
li(ng-repeat="parcel in parcels | filter : filterActiveAreaParcels")
```

I want to run some jQuery plugin that enhances the look of loaded elements after the filter function runs and elements are rendered in DOM. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your filter is not doing some crazy asynchronous stuff and your *parcel* list has a reasonable number of items (see Misko's SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/1095616)) than this [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/BO1DhE4O0rS9OOYzJpEb/preview) should do the job. Notice how custom filter in this plnkr is doing some relatively expensive operation (looping over 1m iterations), but $scope.$watch inside the my-plugin directive is still able to call the jquery plugin on time for each filtered item in the list.

In case your jquery plugin is still being called before ng-repeat is done than you might try with $timeout() inside the directive.